# Qt3D: Scale entity size according to a distance between entity and camera

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, qt3d, pyside2

It is easy to resize entity in a code:

```
self.transform = Qt3DCore.QTransform()
self.transform.setScale(1.5)
```

But I want to resize entity dynamically. I want that my entity enlarge when I move camera away from it or shrinks when I approach my camera. Is it possible to do this using proper shaders?

Comment: Why don't you simply set the scale this way when the camera moves? Why make it complicated and use shaders?

Comment: In my opinion it is better to use GPU than CPU.

Comment: This is of course true for computationally-intensive highly-parallelizable applications like the massive amount of matrix multiplications necessary to render a 3D scene. Depending on your program, the camera position can get updated 60 - 200 times per second (fps). A CPU is easily capable of handling this number of calls and I assume that Qt3D actually handles scaling like you want to achieve it - with a shader that uses a matrix that scales the vertices. Btw, you somehow have to get the new scale to the GPU, i.e. you need to CPU to pass it on -> keep it consistent use Qt3D's functionality.

Comment: If you _really_ _really_ _really_ want to do it your way (although I'd refrain from it) you need to create your own material - effect - technique - render pass with the desired scale as a settable on your material. You then need to pass on the scale to the render pass and add it as a parameter. This way you can use it in your custom shader (also set on the render pass) using the name you specified. You can find on the internet how to scale and object in an OpenGL shader.

Comment: Thank you again, @FlorianBluem. I will do it your way.

Comment: You're welcome! If you experience massive performance issues with this method, come back and we'll find a solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177936-draw-an-object-that-looks-the-same-size-regarles-the-distance-in-perspective-view).

where is a code which I have added added to my vertex shader:

```
in vec3 vertexPosition;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;

void main()
{
    float reciprScaleOnscreen = 0.005;
    float w = (modelViewProjection * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).w;
    w *= reciprScaleOnscreen;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjection * vec4(vertexPosition.xyz * w , 1.0);
}
```

So there is no need to scale entities in a program. It is simpler to use a shader.

Comment: Of course it is possible to use a shader, but _simpler_ depends on whether you are using custom materials. I thought you were not, that's why I suggested using Qt3D's built-in functionality ;)